# Using a license string to play widevine DRM protected content on ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, drm, widevine

I am trying to play a dash file that is Widevine DRM protected on ExoPlayer (v2.5.4). I do not have access to the license server but there is a proxy server that I can make an API call to retrieve the license response. The license server contains the following response:

1. Base64 encoded license string
2. ContentKeys which is a list of two strings (looks like base64 encoded again)

Is there a way to pass these values in ExoPlayer directly? Essentially, I am trying to play DRM-protected content without a URL. Similar question: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widevine and other DRM systems will actually encrypt the license request and response so simply getting a copy of the license response will not provide you the media decryption key for the content in a way that you can access it, if that is what you mean. In other words the license response it built such that only the DRM client on the device can read it properly and extract the key.

If you mean that there is some proxy between your player making the Widevine request and the license server, then this should not matter so long as the proxy does not alter or update the request and response.

You may mean that you actually have access to the media encryption key itself - if so, you can simply decrypt the content yourself separately in your app or on your device and provide it to a player or you could,  update the manifest and provide the key via another method, the Clearkey mechanism in DASH as an example.

Comment: Thank you for the response Mick. I will check if the proxy server does not mess with the original license in any form.